# Reactive Extensions (Rx) execute periodic task

Tags: scheduled-tasks, reactive-programming, rxjs

I'm using Rx and want to execute a task periodically, let's say, every 1 minute.

My task is about to fetch, asynchronously, Feeds from an array of URLs and it's working properly:

```
var rssLinks = ["http://host1/rss.xml", "http://host2/rss.xml", "http://host3/rss.xml"];

// My Task
var task = Rx.Observable.from(rssLinks)
.flatMap(functions.fetchFeeds);

task.subscribe(function(feed) {
    console.log("\nFeed " + feed.title + ", " + feed.link);
});
```

So. I've read about Scheduler and its schedulePeriodic method BUT I can't execute my task periodically.

```
var disposable = Rx.Scheduler.timeout.schedulePeriodic(
 60000, /* 1 minute */
 function () {
      // Execute My Task...        
 });
```

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You're just looking for [Rx.Observable.interval](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/core/operators/interval.md), so something like this will do:

```
var taskResults = Rx.Observable.interval(60000).flatMap(function() {
  return Rx.Observable.from(rssLinks).flatMap(functions.fetchFeeds);
});

taskResults.subscribe(function(x) {
  // do whatever here.
});
```

#### Edit: The "what if I want rssLinks to determin my intervals" answer (from comments)

So something like this, maybe?

```
var rssLinks = [{ interval: 5000, url: 'http://whatever'}, { interval: 3000, url: 'https://foobar' }];

var taskResults = Rx.Observable.from(rssLinks).flatMap(function(rssLink) {
  return Rx.Observable.interval(rssLink.interval).map(function(rssLink) {
    return functions.fetchFeeds(rssLink.url);
  });
});
```

Comment: one last thing @ben, how do I set an specific interval for each rssLink. This is rssLink[0] to be requested every 1 minute, rssLink[1] every 5 minutes and rssLink[2] every 2 minutes. Do I need to create separated tasks and then suscribe for them OR this can be done in the actual taskResults?  Thanks once again:)

Comment: In that case, you might want to inverse it, and have the observable from rssLinks on the outside, feeding into an observable of intervals...

Comment: Added a second example

Comment: (it presumes you've changed your rssLinks to include object literals with urls and intervals)

Comment: Nice! Thank you so much @ben for the simple and awesome examples :)